# Symfony form date range plus existing date

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form which I use for creating and updating an entity. One of the attributes is a date, `startDate`, which input allows this year and next year. So currently, 2019 and 2020. This is my code in **TestType.php**:

```
->add('startDate', DateType::class, [
    'years' => range(date('Y'), date('Y') +1),
])
```

This works as expected. There is one problem I face when a user wants to update an entity with a data with a year from the past, for example `2017`. What I would like in that case is to change the range to that year (2017) until now + 1 year (2020). Is there any way this can be achieved in the **TestType.php** file?

Comment: Do you have access to the data here that tells you you are updating existing data and what the date was in that case?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I can pass it from my controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the start year on pre set data event like:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $event->getForm()->add('startDate', DateType::class, [
        'years' => range(
            $event->getData()->getStartDate() ?
                $event->getData()->getStartDate()->format('Y') :
                date('Y'),
            date('Y')+1
         ),
    ]);
});
```

[Symfony's form events documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)

Comment: Seems to work well. The only issue I faced was the `getYear()` method was not recognised. I changed this by simply formatting the date, replacing  `getYear()` with `format('Y')`.

Comment: Answer updated. Don't know why I wrote getYear... Dont forget to mark your question as "Answered" ;)